# SQL previous/next non-equal datetime in group

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table created by:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
    category INT,
    event_id VARCHAR(MAX),
    event_time DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES
(1, 'event1', '2021-01-12 19:00:00'),
(1, 'event2', '2021-01-12 19:00:00'),
(2, 'event3', '2021-01-12 19:00:00'),
(2, 'event4', '2021-01-12 19:30:00'),
(2, 'event5', '2021-01-12 22:30:00'),
(2, 'event6', '2021-01-12 22:30:00'),
(1, 'event7', '2021-01-12 19:30:00'),
(1, 'event8', '2021-01-12 19:30:00'),
(2, 'event9', '2021-01-12 22:30:00'),
(1, 'event10', '2021-01-12 20:00:00')
```

Which results in:

```
category    event_id    event_time
------------------------------------------------
1           event1      2021-01-12 19:00:00.000
1           event2      2021-01-12 19:00:00.000
2           event3      2021-01-12 19:00:00.000
2           event4      2021-01-12 19:30:00.000
2           event5      2021-01-12 22:30:00.000
2           event6      2021-01-12 22:30:00.000
1           event7      2021-01-12 19:30:00.000
1           event8      2021-01-12 19:30:00.000
2           event9      2021-01-12 22:30:00.000
1           event10     2021-01-12 20:00:00.000
```

I want to add two new columns: `time_of_next_event_in_group` and `time_of_previous_event_in_group` (pretty self explanatory I think).

I have tried to do this using `LAG`/`LEAD` but it doesn't really work when the previous event in the group has the same `event_time`. For clarity, we want the time of next/previous event whose `event_time` is different. The expected result would be:

```
category    event_id    event_time                  time_of_previous_event_in_group time_of_next_event_in_group
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           event1      2021-01-12 19:00:00.000     NULL                            2021-01-12 19:30:00.000
1           event2      2021-01-12 19:00:00.000     NULL                            2021-01-12 19:30:00.000
2           event3      2021-01-12 19:00:00.000     NULL                            2021-01-12 19:30:00.000
2           event4      2021-01-12 19:30:00.000     2021-01-12 19:00:00.000         2021-01-12 22:30:00.000
2           event5      2021-01-12 22:30:00.000     2021-01-12 19:30:00.000         NULL
2           event6      2021-01-12 22:30:00.000     2021-01-12 19:30:00.000         NULL
1           event7      2021-01-12 19:30:00.000     2021-01-12 19:00:00.000         2021-01-12 20:00:00.000
1           event8      2021-01-12 19:30:00.000     2021-01-12 19:00:00.000         2021-01-12 20:00:00.000
2           event9      2021-01-12 22:30:00.000     2021-01-12 19:30:00.000         NULL
1           event10     2021-01-12 20:00:00.000     2021-01-12 19:30:00.000         NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the next query can be helpful:

```
SELECT 
    t.category,
    t.event_id,
    t.event_time,
    MAX(b.event_time) AS time_of_previous_event_in_group,
    MIN(a.event_time) AS time_of_next_event_in_group
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table1 b ON t.category = b.category AND t.event_time > b.event_time
LEFT JOIN table1 a ON t.category = a.category AND t.event_time < a.event_time
GROUP BY t.category, t.event_id, t.event_time
ORDER BY LEN(t.event_id), t.event_id;
```

[Try SQL here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=37886610d035f8eb8a0ac2293a6169f9&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2017)

```
+==========+==========+=========================+=================================+=============================+
| category | event_id | event_time              | time_of_previous_event_in_group | time_of_next_event_in_group |
+==========+==========+=========================+=================================+=============================+
| 1        | event1   | 2021-01-12 19:00:00.000 | (null)                          | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000     |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1        | event2   | 2021-01-12 19:00:00.000 | (null)                          | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000     |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2        | event3   | 2021-01-12 19:00:00.000 | (null)                          | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000     |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2        | event4   | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000 | 2021-01-12 19:00:00.000         | 2021-01-12 22:30:00.000     |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2        | event5   | 2021-01-12 22:30:00.000 | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000         | (null)                      |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2        | event6   | 2021-01-12 22:30:00.000 | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000         | (null)                      |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1        | event7   | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000 | 2021-01-12 19:00:00.000         | 2021-01-12 20:00:00.000     |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1        | event8   | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000 | 2021-01-12 19:00:00.000         | 2021-01-12 20:00:00.000     |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2        | event9   | 2021-01-12 22:30:00.000 | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000         | (null)                      |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1        | event10  | 2021-01-12 20:00:00.000 | 2021-01-12 19:30:00.000         | (null)                      |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: It's a shame if you can't do this with a window function but this way works - thank you!